# PostgreSQL transaction variables

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, transactions, postgresql-9.1

This question is sort of a follow up to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502669/how-to-tell-if-record-has-changed-in-postgres), but it's different enough of a topic that I feel like it merits it's own discussion.  For a bit of background, you can refer to it.

As a part of a new file importing system, I am building an audit system based on this wiki [page](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus). But, one of the things that I would like to include in the audit trail is the file name of the file that the data came from (these files are archived for long term storage so if there are questions, I can always go back).

One way I could go it is to create a import_batch record and record the name of the file there and then just stamp records when they update. Which is the path that I'm going down. But, it feels a bit clunky in a way. I'm been pondering the idea of trying to have the audit trigger be able to get the import_batch_id without it having to be in the NEW.* record. It seems like to me there are at least a couple of ways I might be able to accomplish this.

1. I could have a function that could create a temp table and store any information in it that I want (such as batch # or file name or whatever). This seem pretty clean and as I understand it would only live for the duration of the transaction. And as I understand it, it wouldn't have to worry about naming collisions. Each transaction would have a temp file named "tmp_import_info".
2. If I only care about the import_batch_id (which has a seq), I could probably just get the current value of the sequencer. I'm not a 100% sure how this would behave in a multi-user setting. I would think it would be possible for trans#1 to create import_batch_id #222 and then trans#2 to start and get #223. And then my audit trail would record the wrong data.

Are there other options that I'm not seeing here?  Is there a way to add a transaction/session variable?  Basically, something like pg_settings (but, that does allow for inserts, updates and deletes of values).

It feels like the best option might be the temp table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main good news for **variant 2.** is - quoting [the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-sequence.html):

> `currval`
>
> Return the value most recently obtained by `nextval` for this sequence in the current session. (An error is reported if `nextval` has never been called for this sequence in this session.) Because this is returning a session-local value, it gives a predictable answer whether or not other sessions have executed `nextval` since the current session did.

Store your import file names in a table with a **[`serial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) primary key**. You can refer to *your* last value from the sequence with `currval` or `lastval`. **Concurrent users cannot interfere.** As long as you don't foil this path inside your own transaction yourself, this is safe.

Comment: Ok.  Makes sense.  Since it's on an audit trigger then it is possible that could get edited outside of the context of a regular import (aka via script from pgAdminIII).  In which case I could probably just trap for SQLSTATE '55000'.  I run the slight risk of someone in a pgAdminIII session having run a script that affects the import_batch table...  but, feels like a risk/weakness that I can live with.