# trigger or calculated columns or update or view

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have two csv files `file1.csv` and `file2.csv` I load those files in
two tables in a database '`table1`' and '`table2`'. `table1` contains
`two columns`, those columns use `table2` columns to calculate their
values, and after that the row of `table2` can be deleted because it
used just to `update` `table1`.

My question is:

Which solution is better:

1. When insert in table2 executes a trigger that update the two columns
   in table1 then  delete current row from table2 because it used just
   to calculate the two columns of table1.
2. Delete table2 and do just update table1 when loading file2.
3. Create the two columns as calculated columns, so they will be
   virtual columns only.
4. Create view composed of all columns of table1 and add two calculated
   columns in this view. You can propose another solution

Answer (score 1):

#### 5:

- Create a `TEMPORARY` staging table `table2`. Temporary tables perform much better (and are not persisted).
- `COPY` file2.csv into it.
- `UPDATE` table1.

The temporary table is dropped at the end of the session automatically. Code example here:
[How to tell if record has changed in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502669/how-to-tell-if-record-has-changed-in-postgres/12503305#12503305)

For repeated use, you might keep an empty persisted `table2` as template for the temporary table like demonstrated in the linked answer.
Or even put all of it into a plpgsql function (that's what I would do).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the [file_fdw](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html) FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER to read the file2.csv from within the db (without having to load it) and insert the calculated results into `table1`. This assumes that you are using Postgres 9.1+, and that your file2.csv isn't too big. The suggestion from Erwin is probably the most useful solution, however.